# Problem with react context, not getting updated value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with react context. I have my context file, I have a nav.js file, a protectedRoute.js file which I need to make a page private. Then I have an app.js file where I check an API to see if the user is logged in, and I set the "useLogedin" value and pass it to the context provider.

file app.js

```
function App() {

    const [useLogedin, setState] = useState("not");      
    
    

    useEffect(() => {

      async function getAuth(){
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/isAuth",[]);
        const data = await response.json();
        
        const auth = data.body.isAuth;

        if(auth === "true"){
          setState("auth");
        }else if (auth === "false"){
          setState("not");
        }
       
      }

      getAuth();
    
    })
  
  return (
   <>
    
    <authContext.Provider value= {useLogedin} >
      <Nav />
        <BrowserRouter>
      
          <Routes>
          
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/dashboard' element={<ProtectedDashboardRoute Component={<Dashboard/>} />}/>
            
          


            {/* {useLogedin === 'auth' ? <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} /> : <Navigate replace to = "/" />} */}
            
          
        </Routes>
        
      </BrowserRouter>
      </authContext.Provider>
   </>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

file ProtectedDashboardRoute.js

```
export default function ProtectedDashboardRoute() {

    const value = useContext(authContext);
    console.log("is Auth: ");
    console.log(value);


    return value === "auth" ? <Dashboard/> : <Navigate to = "/" />

}
```

file nav.js

```
export default function Nav(){

    const isAuth = useContext(authContext)
    return(
        <Header>
            <Logo><Span>GREEN</Span> ENERGY HOME</Logo> 
            {isAuth === "auth" ? <a>Logout</a> : <Login href="https://my_domain/login?response_type=code&client_id=7eek42g0k9l5v2sdt6r49ogup3&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001/auth" >Login</Login>}
            
        </Header>
    )
}
```

authContext.js

```
const authContext = React.createContext();
export {authContext};
```

my problem that when I request context value with useContext in ProtectedDashboardRoute.js file the value is always not, I noticed that in browser console it does it twice, first time it has value "not", second time it has value" auth", can you help me? however when i do it in the nav.js file to show 'logout' and hide 'login' and it works fine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the initial value of your state & the context. The promise is resolved later on, meaning that the first value your components receive is `"not"` and later on, when the auth request you've sent via `fetch("http://localhost:3001/isAuth")` resolves, the value is updated to `"auth"` or `"not"` again.

You can avoid this by setting the initial value to a loading state and not rendering the rest of your components before the auth request is resolved.

```
function App() {
  const [useLogedin, setState] = useState("loading");

  // Your useEffect implementation

  return (<authContext.Provider value={useLogedin} >
    {useLogedin !== "loading" &&
      <>
        <Nav />
        <BrowserRouter>
          {/* Rest of your code */}
        </BrowserRouter>
      </>
    }
  </authContext.Provider>);
}
```